# Annoying auto-start PC issue

Tags: troubleshooting, vbscript

I just removed obs from my PC and im keep getting this message, non-stop. Can you please help?

[image: Click here to wiev image]

I tried to search for program who is maybe activating this file, but its missing, to remove it.

Comment: What did you do?  Delete the AppData folder?   If so, not a good idea.

Comment: No, i didnt do that, i mannually removed OBS from installer

Comment: Try DISM / SFC and see if that corrects the issue.   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Could you translate that dialog message into English for us?

Comment: @Tetsujin yes i can,

Comment: Unable to find script file:

Comment: These commands arent working, it just show blank black

Comment: More details : To test Windows integrity run [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc i typed these cmds but nothing poped up it just was looking like @ echo was off (i typed commands then there was blank black and i couldny type anything

Comment: Please read the links on how to run these commands, then try again.

Comment: @harrymc I know how to, because i did it earlier ill try again.

Comment: @John Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.
For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at
windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline
repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.  **This showed up when i did everything**

Comment: @harrymc Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.
For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at
windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline
repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.  **This showed up when i did everything**

Comment: Check if anything related to the software is still in task manager's Startup (or Autostart or whatever language-dependent name). Check the startup folder (Win+R `shell:startup`). Search for parts of the non-existent file, e.g. `obs-studio` in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to install the following two utilities.

- [Autoruns for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
  to search for all Startup items containing the sub-string "obs"
- [RegScanner](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html)
  to search for registry values containing the sub-string "obs-studio".

Delete (carefully) all the found items. This should get rid of this
Startup message and terminate the clean up after OBS.

Next time, I suggest using
[Revo Uninstaller Free](https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/)
in order to uninstall products while cleaning out all their left-overs.

Comment: I just got it fixed by youtube and i didnt read this  sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Just some registry userinit value change from "C:\Windows\system32\userinit.exe." to "C:\Windows\system32\userinit.exe"

Comment: @AstroMan you should make that an answer

Answer (score 0):

#### I tried to search for the program that is displaying this dialog

> I  manually removed OBS from installer

You need to clean up after the manual remove.

---

#### Iobit Unstaller

> IObit Uninstaller 3 is a light and FREE uninstall tool that helps you
> to remove unwanted programs and leftovers completely without any
> hassle. It detects and categorizes all of the installed programs, and
> allows bulk uninstallation with just ONE click!

Source [IObit Uninstaller 3](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html)

---

#### Revo Uninstaller

> Revo Uninstaller Pro helps you to uninstall software and remove unwanted programs installed on your computer easily! Even if you have problems uninstalling and cannot uninstall them from "Windows Programs and Features (Add or Remove Programs)" control panel applet.
>
> Revo Uninstaller is a much faster and more powerful alternative to "Windows Programs and Features (Add or Remove Programs)" applet! It has very powerful features to uninstall and remove programs.

There is a freeware version available.

Source [Revo Uninstaller Pro](http://www.revouninstaller.com/index.html)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [IObit Uninstaller 3](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html) or [Revo Uninstaller Pro](http://www.revouninstaller.com/index.html) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.